# Passing File with intent, how do i retrieve it

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here is what I am passing. `pictureFile` is a `File`

```
Intent intent = new Intent (context, ShowPicActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", pictureFile);
```

In the next activity which one of the getters do I use to get it?

`Intent intent = getIntent();` .....?

Comment: Do not pass File object. You better pass URI to that file.

Comment: Have you seen anywhere in android sdk someone passed/returned File object via Intent? URI is the android way to do this. I'll try to find an article why you shouldn't do this.

Comment: Ok thank you, If it's the best way I will do it that way then! I just want to know why!

Comment: because File is more than just a refence to a resource. When you pass object via intent a new copy will be created and I'm not sure that the copy of File will be viable in all use cases. If you need to pass a referense use URI, if you need to share File object inside your app share it some other way without serializing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
YourPictureClass picture = (YourPictureClass)getIntent().getExtras().get("picture");
```

By calling `getExtras()` in your `Intent` you get an instance of `Bundle`.
With the normal `get()` in class `Bundle` you can read every `Object` you pass to the calling `Intent`. The only thing you have to do is to parse it back to the `class` your object is an instance of.

Answer (score 14):

File implements **serializable** ( first thing to check to send an object through an intent. ) 
( [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) )

so you can do it, just cast the resulting object to File like this :

```
File pictureFile = (File)getIntent.getExtras().get("picture");
```

It should be fine.
(it use [the getter for 'object'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) which needs a **serializable** object and return it. The cast should be enough.)

Comment: Wouldn't `getSerializableExtra()` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 8):

You can send it like this:

`intent.putExtra("MY_FILE", myFile);`

and retrieve it like this:

`File myFile = (File)intent.getSerializableExtra("MY_FILE");`

**However**, it may be better (anyone?) to send the file as a string reference, in which case you could send as:

`intent.putExtra("MY_FILE_STRING", myFile.toString());`

and retrieve/reconstruct like this:

`File myFile = new File(intent.getStringExtra("MY_FILE_STRING"));`