# convert a String into an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent of action type `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. I wrap this intent into another intent object like this:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(cordova.getActivity(), ReceivePhotosActivity.class);
//imageIntent is an Intent object
activityIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, imageIntent);
this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, activityIntent, 0);
```

On the `ReceivePhotosActivity` i parse the incoming intent and store my imageIntent into a string.

```
Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
String imageIntent = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
```

Now i need this `imageIntent` in order to process Images. As a string I am unable to do so as I require the `intent.getAction()` and `intent.getType()`. So how can i convert my `String imageIntent` to an `Intent` object

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

from [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

more reference link: [Passing File with intent, how do i retrieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397165/passing-file-with-intent-how-do-i-retrieve-it)

Hope them help you.